# Минимизация расхода памяти при получении и парсинге данных (JSON)

Tags: android, json, память, парсер

Доброго вреемени суток, интересует вопрос: Минимизация расхода памяти при получении и парсинге данных (`JSON`)
К примеру получаю строку `json` размером в **6Мб** и дальше ее обрабатывать создавая объекты - не очень рационально, как сделать так что бы эта строка парсилась так сказать по-этапно, то есть скачивалась не полностью ибо не хочется получить *"Приложение не отвечает"*. Зарание спасибо

Comment: на чем разрабатываете то?

Comment: что бы не было _"приложение не отвечает"_  (win-приложение?) запускайте парсер в отдельном потоке, но опять же зависит от технологии реализации.

Comment: Разрабатываю под андроид, в АндрСтудио. В АсинкТаске запускаю парсер, но выходит так что парсинг забирает почти все выделенные ресурсы приложению

Answer (score 1):

Пока строка вся не получена, парсер не будет парсить часть.
Например, `{data... 100000 символов ... }`. Без последней скобки корректно не распарсишь.

Решается просто - не слать такое сразу, а частями.

Comment: этак и SAX-парсеров для XML не бывает?

Comment: @teran, есть, но не `json`.

Comment: что-то [тут (первая ссылка с гугла)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444380/is-there-a-streaming-api-for-json)  с вами не особо согласятся, но никто не мешает реализовать такой парсер самостоятельно.

Comment: OK, есть. Не знаю насколько это можно считать тем, что ожидается в вопросе, но пусть. Ответьте про SAX.

Comment: Окей, спасибо. А как парсить частями, через сторонюю библиотеку?

Answer (score 1):

Не каждые 6 мб json`а занимают одинаково большое/маленькое количество ресурсов. Важную роль играет то, в какие объекты языка трансформируется исходный json, и какой парсер занимается парсингом. Если вы парсите собственными силами, то вероятнее всего занимаетесь изобретением велосипеда - есть уже множество библиотек с оптимизированным алгоритмом разбора.

Comment: а откуда взялась java?

Comment: Ой, прочитал метку json как java. Исправил, но сути это не меняет.